# how do you add values in pandas dataframe column based on group values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this

```py
print(df)
    
#Hostname  Slot Port Reserved
#Server1     1    1    0
#Server1     1    2    0
#Server1     2    3    1
#Server2     2    1    1
#Server2     2    2    0
#Server2     2    3    1
#Server3     1    1    0
#Server3     2    2    0
#Server3     3    3    1
```

I need to sum `Reserved` column by `Hostname` and `Slot` columns.

```
Hostname  Slot  Total_Reserved
Server1     1      1   
Server2     2      2  
Server3     1      1
```

I tried this to no avail:

```py
new_df = df.groupby(['Hostname', 'Slot', 'Reserved']).sum()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) is the way to go, but your current command is incorrect.

You need to remove "Reserved" from the groups:

```
out = (df
       .query('Reserved > 0')
       .groupby(['Hostname', 'Slot'], as_index=False)
       ['Reserved'].sum()
       )
```

Output:

```
  Hostname  Slot  Reserved
0  Server1     2         1
1  Server2     2         2
2  Server3     3         1
```

Alternatively:

```
out = (df
       .groupby(['Hostname', 'Slot'])
       [['Reserved']].sum()
       .add_prefix('Total_').reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
  Hostname  Slot  Total_Reserved
0  Server1     1               0
1  Server1     2               1
2  Server2     2               2
3  Server3     1               0
4  Server3     2               0
5  Server3     3               1
```

Comment: this is good but I need to count reserve=0 as well, if reserve=0, I need to    put that in as 0.

Comment: Then remove the `query`

Comment: quick question. If the Reserved was string and I wanted to count the number of occurences, what function I could use?

Comment: What do you mean? For the number of unique occurrences, use `nunique`. For the count of each values you'd need a fully different logic: a `crosstab`.